# window.onload in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have use the example of sizzle and there I got window.onload in the last of the code.

What does this means.

My code is like this:

```
var init = function () {
    var trail = Sizzle;
    var foo = trail('.foo');
    foo[0].onmouseover = function () {
        this.style.backgroundColor = (this.style.backgroundColor.indexOf('blue') === 0) ? 'yellow' : 'blue';
    };
    foo[1].onmouseover = function () {
        this.style.backgroundColor = (this.style.backgroundColor.indexOf('red') === 0) ? 'yellow' : 'red';
        jQuery(foo[1]).after("<b>Hello</b>");
    }
    foo[2].onmouseover = function () {
        this.style.backgroundColor = (this.style.backgroundColor.indexOf('green') === 0) ? 'yellow' : 'green';
        jQuery(foo[3]).toggle("slow");
        jQuery('b').remove();
    }
};
window.onload = init;
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Function init() start to work only after window(page) load finish.

Answer (score 6):

It means that you are setting the `init` function to handle the `onload` event of the document. The `init` function will be called when all the content in the page has loaded.

As you are using jQuery, you should use the jQuery events instead. The DOM events can only have one handler (unless you write code to chain the handlers), but the jQuery events can have multiple handlers:

```
$(document).load(init);
```

If you have more than one script in the page that uses the `onload` event, one will replace the other. Even if you use jQuery events, a script that hooks up the DOM event will take over the jQuery event handler, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095401/is-google-map-not-loading-if-i-have-a-javascript-error-on-page-google-maps-ap). Using the jQuery event in all scripts solves that.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong with the answer, it can't improve it.

Comment: window.onload ≠ document.onload.  The OP wants to know what window.onload() does and you tell him to use document.onload. Why?

Comment: The crazy thing is, you already know this!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready

Comment: note that the 'load' event is removed in jQuery 3.0

Answer (score 2):

This means that on the load of window the `function init` will be executed.