# mvc 4 jquery functions with dropdownlist and window.onload issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue getting two sets of functions to work correctly. I have a change function that shows and hides a div that works as intended but can not get the window.onload function to correcly work when loading the page and not affecting how the .change functions work.

Function Script:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script>

    $(function () {
        window.onload = function () {
            if ($("#SelectedGenderId").val() == "3") {
                $(".gender-description").show();
            } else {
                $(".gender-description").hide();
            }
            if ($("#SelectedSettingId").val() == "1") {
                $(".setting-description").show();
            } else {
                $(".setting-description").hide();
            }
        }

        $("#GenderId").change(function () {
            if ($("#GenderId").val() == 3) {
                $(".gender-description").show();
            } else {
                $(".gender-description").hide();
            }
        });

        $("#SettingId").change(function () {
            if ($("#SettingId").val() == 1) {
                $(".setting-description").show();
            } else {
                $(".setting-description").hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The .change functions work as expected but the .onload does not. Am I using the .onload correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to David Tansey for pushing me into the right direction. After looking further at the .onload function and trying to reconcile the difference between SelectedGenderId which needed to be a string for use with the dropdownlistfor html helper I came up with this solution for correctly identifying the state of the functions (using alert() to see when the IF statements would fire.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        window.onload = function () {
            if (('@Model.Client.GenderId') == 3) {
                $(".gender-description").show();
            } else {
                $(".gender-description").hide();
            }
            if (('@Model.Client.SettingId') == 1) {
                $(".setting-description").show();
            } else {
                $(".setting-description").hide();
            }
        }

        $("#GenderId").change(function () {
            if ($("#GenderId").val() == 3) {
                $(".gender-description").show();
            } else {
                $(".gender-description").hide();
           }
        });

        $("#SettingId").change(function () {
            if ($("#SettingId").val() == 1) {
                $(".setting-description").show();
            } else {
                $(".setting-description").hide();
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

And for anyone trying to implement something similar here is the  info:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Client.GenderId, "Gender")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedGenderId, Model.Genders, new { id = "GenderId" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Client.GenderId)
    </div>

    <div class="gender-description">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Client.GenderDescription)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Client.GenderDescription)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Client.GenderDescription)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Client.SettingId, "Settings")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedSettingId, Model.Settings, new { id = "SettingId" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Client.SettingId)
    </div>

    <div class="setting-description">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Client.SettingDescription)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Client.SettingDescription)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Client.SettingDescription)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the problem is due to your tests (`if` statements) being different in your `onload()` from the way you are handling it in the `change()` events.

In `onload()` you use the following test:

`if ($("#SelectedGenderId").val() == "3")`

with a **string** literal

but in the `change()` events you are using

`if ($("#GenderId").val() == 3)`

with an **integer** literal.

I am suspecting that even though the controls you are testing are different in each case, that you did not really intend to deal with the values in two different manners.

Hope that helps.

Comment: There are so many different ways to handle dropdownlists, I settled on using a viewModel that passes in a SelectedGenderId as a string (can not use an int) and a selectList. This works very well with the .change function. I don't want to get into the pros and cons of how to implement a dropdownlist here. Is there a way to handle the the onload() function using the GenderId value that is currently sent in  within the model?

Comment: Is your `onload()` being called at all?  Place an `alert()` in there.  I am a little bit confused by the `window.onload` being specified inside of the `$(document).ready()` (in your case using the shorthand `$( function () {})`).  Take a look at the accepted answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095401/is-google-map-not-loading-if-i-have-a-javascript-error-on-page-google-maps-ap  Hope that helps.

Comment: I placed an alert() inside the window.onload call and yes it is being called. and the .change functions are working. So the question becomes is how do I look at any data coming in from the model within that .onload function?